# How do i edit a .dat file?

Tags: file

i have a game that i play, and i want to edit the .dat files in that game to make a difference in the game. My question is how do i do this?[image]

I have tried multiple things but i can't figure out how to make it work. I also have a couple of other files that have .ddf extentions. if anyone can help me i would appreciate it!

I have tried the following:

- decode the .dat (Couldn't find out how)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that this file is a `.dat` file extention **does not** mean you can edit it as text. The program may use this file as a binary file, which you cannot edit.